# Zoom in and out

Tags: android

Here is the code I am trying to achieve zoom In and Zoom out for the Image. It gets zoom but when it goes out of screen it gets crashed ... also when I zoom out the size of the image shrinks and then later on it get crashed. I want to limit the Zoom In to one level and also to the Zoom out to the original position.

and it goes on scaling to the left top of the screen as the mid point of the image changes ...

Please help to achieve that ....thanks

```
package com.imageviewzoomactivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageViewZoomActivityActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {
   private static final String TAG = "Touch";
   // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
   Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
   Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
   Matrix savedMatrix2 = new Matrix();

   private static final int WIDTH = 0;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 1;
   // We can be in one of these 3 states
   static final int NONE = 0;
   static final int DRAG = 1;
   static final int ZOOM = 2;
   int mode = NONE;

   // Remember some things for zooming
   PointF start = new PointF();
   PointF mid = new PointF();
   float oldDist = 1f;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main);
      ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
      view.setOnTouchListener(this);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
      ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
      int rotation = 25;
      // Dump touch event to log
      dumpEvent(event);

      // Handle touch events here...
      switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
      /*case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         savedMatrix.set(matrix);
         start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
         Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
         mode = DRAG;
         break;*/



      case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
         oldDist = spacing(event);
         Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
         if (oldDist > 10f) {
            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
            midPoint(mid, event);
            mode = ZOOM;
            Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
         }
         break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

         mode = NONE;
         Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
         savedMatrix.set(matrix);
        // matrix.postRotate(90);
         break;


      case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
         if (mode == DRAG) {
            // ...
            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                  event.getY() - start.y);
         }
         else if (mode == ZOOM) {
            float newDist = spacing(event);
            Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
            if (newDist > 10f) {
               matrix.set(savedMatrix);
               float scale = newDist / oldDist;
               matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
            }
         }
         break;
      }

      view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
      return true; // indicate event was handled
   }



/** Show an event in the LogCat view, for debugging */
   private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
      String names[] = { "DOWN", "UP", "MOVE", "CANCEL", "OUTSIDE",
            "POINTER_DOWN", "POINTER_UP", "7?", "8?", "9?" };
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      int action = event.getAction();
      int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
      sb.append("event ACTION_").append(names[actionCode]);
      if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
            || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
         sb.append("(pid ").append(
               action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
         sb.append(")");
      }
      sb.append("[");
      for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
         sb.append("#").append(i);
         sb.append("(pid ").append(event.getPointerId(i));
         sb.append(")=").append((int) event.getX(i));
         sb.append(",").append((int) event.getY(i));
         if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
            sb.append(";");
      }
      sb.append("]");
      Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
   }

   /** Determine the space between the first two fingers */
   private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
      float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
      float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
      return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
   }

   /** Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers */
   private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
      float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
      float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
      point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

show image in webview. see this example...

```
String html = new String();
html = ("<html><BODY  ><table  style='margin-top:100px;'  align='center'><tr><td><img src=\""+path+"\" width=\""+800+"px\" height=\""+800+"px\" ></td></tr></table> </BODY></html>" );

webView1.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///sdcard/data/data/com.dharani.jorTablet.Fragments/",
       html,
       "text/html",
       "utf-8",
       "");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this example also

```
         float mScaleFactor1=1.f;
    float gx=0,gy=0;


    //Code for Image Scaling............
    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor1 *= detector.getScaleFactor();




          gx = detector.getFocusX();
            gy = detector.getFocusY();





            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onScaleEnd(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onScaleEnd(detector);


        }
    }
```

finally in onDraw() method call this    //Image Scaling....

```
 **canvas.scale(gx, gy);**
```

Comment: This is nice idea... but the problem is i am making Letter bubble game where left portion of the screen is covered with the Head on Display and the other part of the screen has the gamePlay ... say Treasure hunt kind of display ...NOw in the gamePlay screen I want to zoom in and out the Image which has onsetListener becoz as the bubbles will come up depending on the HeadonDisplay text user has to select the bubble ..I hope you understood my need ....

Comment: I have done everythig using layout with the above code what I showed is the best for my logic ...because i have to recognize the onDown event for my bubble got selected .. and my xml of gamePlay levels are Relative Layout ->  11 ImageViews (1 st Image view contains the background level image) i want to zoom only that ImageVIew or maybe relative layout that can zoom the background Image

Comment: Create dynamic view by extending View class.whenever you extend view class you will get overriden methods like onDraw(),onTouch()...then use the above code.finally add dynamic view to your layout using layoutid.addView(your_dynamicview).

Comment: I have issue wile panning this when i do this canvas.scale(mScaleFactor,mScaleFactor,gx,gy)

Answer (score 0):

If you just want zooming, use `ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener` class. It was methods that make it real easy to adjust the zoom level using matrices.

```
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector){
        ...
    }
```

`detector.getFocuxX()` and `detector.getFocusY()` take care of getting the zoom midpoint so you don't have to calculate that yourself.

Keep a float `scaleFactor` and update with `scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor()`. This way you can control a max and min zoom level.

Sample Code:

```
public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
    //update the current scale
    scaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
    matrix.setScale(scaleFactor, scaleFactor)
}
```

Boom. There you go.

Comment: can u please guide me how to write code for zoom on button click